# can't handle universal links when app is killed ( userActivity is nil )

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to run app by using universal links.
I want to make sure that when I open the app through universal links, the app runs and go to the viewcontroller I want.
it works when app is still alive or already in background. But if the app is killed, the universal links just run the app but not go to the viewcontroller I want.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
        if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb{
            guard let url = userActivity.webpageURL else { return }
            print(url)
        let nextVc = nextVC()
            nextVc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(nextVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

this is what I have done in func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity).it works when app is alive.

```
 func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
...
 let userActivity = connectionOptions.userActivities.first
        if userActivity!.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
            let incomingURL = userActivity!.webpageURL
            let components = NSURLComponents(url: incomingURL!, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)
            print (incomingURL)
        } else {print("nothing") }
..
}
```

And this is what I have tried at func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) .
To see if I can get the url but I found the userActivity is nil.
what should I do?